# Grails form not submitting

Tags: grails, forms, http-post

Here is my Grails (2.3.6) controller:

```
class WidgetController {
    def index() {
        render(
            view: "createNew", 
            model:[
            ]
        )
    }

    def execute() {
        println "Executing form submission!"
        redirect(action: "listAll")
    }

    def listAll() {
        // Does some stuff
    }
}
```

The `index` URL is, say, `http://localhost:8080/myapp/widget`. The idea is that when someone goes to this URL, they are presented with an HTML form. When they fill out the form, they are sent (on the server side) to the `execute()` method, which does some heavy duty stuff and then redirects them to the `listAll()` method which does some final stuff and renders a web page for them to see.

Here is the HTML form on the `createNew.gsp` (rendered from the `index()` method:

```
<g:form name="create-new-form" url="[action:'execute',controller:'widget']">
    <table class="pure-table pure-table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td class="row-header">Fizz:</td>
            <td><g:textField id="app-fizz" name="fizz" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="row-header">Buzz:</td>
            <td><g:textField id="app-buzz" name="buzz" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <g:actionSubmit value="Create" />
</g:form>
```

When I go to this URL and submit the form (clicking the *Create* button) I get redirected to `http://localhost/myapp/widget/execute` which displays one of my customized error pages (basically a "*Sorry this page is unavailable*"-type error.

Additionally, in the log outputs, my `println` stating "*Executing form submission!*" is not firing. This tells me that I don't have something wired correctly: Grails is trying to redirect to an `/execute` URL but somehow isn't linking that URL with my controller's `execute()` method. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
<g:actionSubmit action="execute" value="Create" />
```

If you specify only value for `g:actionSubmit` it creates button with this label and also redirect to action based on this value. If action name is different than button label you should specify `action` and `value` attributes. Take a look at [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html).

Note that if you use `g:actionSubmit` then action attribute of `g:form` will be ignored (which you specified btw.). You'll find more info where it may be useful in docs linked above.

Comment: No problem ;) I've just added some additional info to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use plain `<input type="submit" value="go"/>`. thus the form is submitted to the URI defined in `<g:form>` tag

`g.actionSubmit` or `g.submitButton` are needed, if you want to submit your form somewhere ELSE.